# Python - getting all forms of a word

Tags: python, nltk

I would like to get all forms of a word using python.

For example, Africa would generate: "Africa", "Africanism", "Africanist", "African", ideally even "afro-" as a prefix.

Is there any library which can accomplish this? I have tried both lemminflect and nltk WordNetLemmatizer and they aren't achieving what I want. I believe this is because these aren't technically inflections of "Africa".

Comment: You can try by scraping a 'dictiorary' website with the `request` module and interact with it for search for all the words with the same prefix but it probably won't be accourate 100%

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using a dictionary file [like this](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words).

You can easily find in words_dictionary.json all words with Africa prefix.